# Best database architecture for schedule

Tags: php, mysql, database

So far I have a table for a shift schedule which looks like this

```
id | shift_id | start      | finish
1  | 1        | 2017-11-20 | 2017-11-24
2  | 2        | 2017-11-20 | 2017-11-24
3  | 1        | 2017-11-27 | 2017-12-01
4  | 2        | 2017-11-27 | 2017-12-01
5  | 1        | 2017-12-04 | 2017-12-08
6  | 6        | 2017-12-04 | 2017-12-08
```

I would like to search the database by either a single date or by using a date range and have been using the following to do so:-

```
// Query shift data
$sql = "SELECT * FROM " . SCHEDULE_TABLE . " 
        INNER JOIN " . SHIFTS_TABLE . " ON " . SCHEDULE_TABLE . ".shift_id = " . SHIFTS_TABLE . ".shift_id
        WHERE :startDate >= start AND start < :endDate";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(['startDate' => $startDate, 'endDate' => $endDate]);
```

so if I set $startdate to "2017-11-21" and $endDate to "2017-11-21" I would expect the query to return results with id 1 and 2 (which it does)

However if I search for a range that goes beyond a given week I only get 1 weeks results for example if I set $startDate to "2017-11-22" and endDate to "2017-12-06" I would expect the query to return all 6 rows but it onl returns the first 2 rows.

I know this is likely to be a problem with my query as I am only searching the start column and never using the finish column.

ultimately when the query is returned I will be putting each shift within the date range into an array so if I search "2017-11-20" - "2017-11-24" I would end up with an array:-

```
        {
        date: 2017-11-20
        shift: 1
        date: 2017-11-20
        shift: 2
        date: 2017-11-21
        shift: 1
        date: 2017-11-21
        shift: 2
etc...
}
```

should I be looking to fix my sql query or should I re-structure the table so that I store every single day instead of in 5 day blocks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like an overlapping range problem.  Try this logic in your `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE :startDate < finish AND :endDate > start
```

Here is a demo for the following query which shows that all six records are returned for the date range you mentioned.

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE '2017-11-22' < finish AND '2017-12-06' > start;
```

### Demo

Comment: I had already tried that however that returns 0 results which I was and still am surprised at.

Comment: @Chris I disagree.  My suggested query would return all 6 records for the range you mentioned.  Check the demo.  You must have some other problems in your code.

Comment: you are correct.. I have just tried it again for the 3rd time after looking at your demo... I wish I knew what I had done wrong the first time I tried this method... Thank You

Comment: @Chris Deriving the overlapping range formula can be a bit of work if done from scratch.  But you can always rely on a reference to look it up in the future.